# Wrap function in Symfony 2 controller Methods

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 2, I have a controller which has many methods, I want to be able to wrap methods within all the methods of the controller, else I would have to manually place the code at the end of each function. Has someone ever implement this in Symfony 2?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do at the end of each method?

Comment: Maybe you can solve that with [PHP desctructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor)

Answer (score 0):

If your code concern Response, have a look at kernel.view event.
Ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805462/520114

Otherwise, see other events.